# Strict aliasing rule violation

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

In this [link from the isocpp.org faq](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) in the example provided, a Fred object is being constructed with placement new to a buffer that is being allocated for another object i.e. for

```
char memory[sizeof(Fred)]
```

As I know the strict aliasing rules allows us to do the opposite i.e. for an object of whatever type, we are allowed to have a `char*` point at it and we can dereference that pointer and use it as we want.

But here in the example the opposite is happening. What am I missing?

Comment: What is wrong with the question that gave me the downvote?

Comment: there are too dunces don't care of them. I have given +1. Don't give up to keep up with asking question when you stuck. The website is for learning.

Comment: It would improve the question to show in the question the code you are asking about, instead of having an external link which may change over time, and has several code samples .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placement-new creates a new object. It doesn't alias the old object. The old object (the `char` array in this example) is considered to stop existing when the placement-new executes.

Before placement-new, there is storage filled with `char` objects. After placement-new, there is storage filled with one `Fred` object.

Since there is no aliasing, there are no strict-aliasing problems.

Comment: I believe using `memory` after placement new in this example is undefined behavior. Is that correct? What about `place`?

Comment: I think using memory after that would not be undefined. Because of the snippet StoryTeller posted above. 

So @M.M I think I got it. One thing, if someone now had a pointer char* to memory, outside of this function and knew that in there, is stored an object of Type Fred. He would want to reinterpret_cast it to Fred*. The reason he is allowed to do this is because of 5 in this [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). But then to dereference he would need one of the bullets from Type aliasing from below in that link to hold true to justify it. Right? If yes which?

Comment: Or even in this context this doesn't count as aliasing?

Comment: @esam there is no undefined behaviour in this code.

Comment: @user183833 "aliasing" is using an lvalue of one type to access an object of a different type. Which does not happen in this example. In your case (if I understand you right) the other person could use `Fred` or `char` to access the `Fred` object. (Using `char` would be aliasing, but it is allowed to use char to alias other objects).

Comment: @M.M My question was not about the code as is. I was asking if we *change the code* and use `memory` *after* placement new, is that undefined behavior? What about `place`?

Comment: @esam You would need to post the code you want to ask about, I can't tell what you are suggesting. Perhaps you should start a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The strict aliasing rules doesn't mention that `Fred*` must be cast to `char*`. Only that variables of type `char*` and `Fred*` may point to the same object, and be used to access it.

Quoting [[basic.lval] paragraph 8](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#8)

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through
>   a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is
>   undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
>
>   [..]
> - a char or unsigned char type.

Comment: Yes, but what I understand to happen in the example is the opposite.
The value of the object is being access from the Type Fred.
What this snippet that you posted says is for the other direction i.e.
A Fred object being access from a char type.

Comment: Also is the "dynamic type" here being referred in terms of inheritance?

Comment: @user183833 The snippet doesn't impose either direction. They are both valid in this context. And yes, it's dynamic in terms of inheritance.